# Load .xib file from framework

Tags: swift, xib

I create a framework with Custom View. When I'm try to load this to simulator, it loads but when there's a bug when load in deferent iPhone simulators.

I set the constraints to 0, but the custom view doesn't load in all view.

framework code:

```
@IBDesignable
public class SummaryHeaderView: UIView {
    
    /* View */
    @IBOutlet public var view: UIView!
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpNib()
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpNib()
    }
    
    internal func setUpNib() {
        view = loadNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    internal func loadNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: SummaryHeaderView.self), bundle: bundle)
        guard let summaryHeaderView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else {
            return UIView()
        }
        return summaryHeaderView
    }
    
}
```

app code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

var summary = SummaryHeaderView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    summary = SummaryHeaderView(frame: self.myView.bounds)
    
    myView.addSubview(summary)
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please show sufficient code to allow your code to compile. What is `view`? What is `bounds`? Don't show code that uses undeclared variables.

Comment: That's great, thanks! So what's the problem exactly? Is it that you don't like the _size_ of the loaded view?

Comment: The green background is my .xib file in framework I created. The gray background is the view in my app. I init the green background in my view controller and the height and width should occupy all view.

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed in my answer (below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One serious problem with your code is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    summary = SummaryHeaderView(frame: self.myView.bounds)
}
```

You are assuming here that `self.myView.bounds` is known at the time `viewDidLoad` runs. That assumption is wrong. `viewDidLoad` is too soon for that. Therefore your summary header view shows at the wrong size.

A simple solution would be: instead of using absolute frames everywhere, use *auto layout constraints* everywhere. That way, all your views and subviews will adjust themselves *automatically* no matter how big the screen turns out to be.

Another way to do this is to wait until the size of the view *is* known. For example, move your code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But then you must take extra steps so that you don't add the subview again later, because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called many times during the app's lifetime.